# DirectX11 E_INVALIDARG One or more arguments are invalid

Tags: hlsl, direct3d11

When I am trying to load a Shader result from memory the compiler says: one or more arguments are invalid. Shader compiling successfully but it seems  after `D3DCompileFromFile()` command  in memory is something not correct and  `ID3DBlob` interface does not get correct values for some reason.

```
ID3DBlob*  pBlobFX = NULL;
ID3DBlob*  pErrorBlob = NULL;
hr = D3DCompileFromFile(str, NULL, NULL, NULL, "fx_5_0", NULL, NULL,  &pBlobFX, &pErrorBlob);  //  OK
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    if (pErrorBlob != NULL)
        OutputDebugStringA((char *)pErrorBlob->GetBufferPointer());
    SAFE_RELEASE(pErrorBlob);
    return hr;
}

//  Create the  effect
hr = D3DX11CreateEffectFromMemory(pBlobFX->GetBufferPointer(), pBlobFX->GetBufferSize(), 0, pd3dDevice, ppEffect); //  Error:  E_INVALIDARG One or more arguments are invalid
```

Comment: Which version of Effects are you using? If you use the [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/FX11) version it has a ``D3DX11CompileEffectFromFile`` implemented which does these two steps.

Comment: Please share the details of what was needed to fix your code?

Comment: Chuck I  am using Github   version DXUT and  Effects  libraries.

Comment: What did you change in the code you posted that made it work? Was it switching to the new libraries and using ``D3DX11CompileEffectFromFile``?

Comment: Yeap  exactly when i  switched to new libs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [legacy DirectX SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx) version of Effects for Direct3D 11 only included `D3DX11CreateEffectFromMemory` for creating effects which required using a compiled shader binary blob loaded by the application.

The latest [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/FX11) version includes the other expected functions:

- `D3DX11CreateEffectFromFile` which loads a compiled binary blob from disk and then creates an effect from it.
- `D3DX11CompileEffectFromMemory` which uses the D3DCompile API to compile a `fx` file in memory and then create an effect from it.
- `D3DX11CompileEffectFromFile` which uses the D3DCompile API to compile a provided `fx` file and then create an effect from it.

Using `D3DX11CompileEffectFromFile` instead of trying to do it manually as the original poster tried is the easiest solution here.

> The original library wanted to strongly encourage using build-time rather than run-time compilation of effects. Given that the primary use of Effects 11 today is developer education, this was unnecessarily difficult for new developers to use so the GitHub version now includes all four possible options for creating effects.

*Note: The `fx_5_0` profile in the HLSL compiler is deprecated, and is required to use Effects 11.*

Comment: Chuck did  i understand correctly ?!  i  mustn't point shader flag in  function  "fx_5_0" or what  ?  :)

Comment: I'm saying that you can use Effects 11 and the latest HLSL compiler still supports the required ``fx_5_0`` profile, *however* it is considered a deprecated feature. See [this thread](https://fx11.codeplex.com/discussions/450240) for more details.